# pinterest Secor configuratio

Tags: apache-kafka, pinterest

I work an application which uses secor.
There is a configuration parameter

```
secor.kafka.topic_filter=.*
secor.kafka.topic_blacklist=
```

Does the wildcard .* mean it is should consume from all kafka topics and topic_blacklist = <None> means no topics are blacklisted for uploading to s3 ?

Comment: Seems like a correct description to me. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: There are no issues. I just want to know what these values and parameters mean.

Comment: It explains it right in the file... https://github.com/pinterest/secor/blob/master/src/main/config/secor.common.properties#L20

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Consumers can subscribe using a regex

Sometimes, writing a regex is hard to ignore certain topics, so a blacklist will ignore those